# Web2py: Can you password protect a page?

Tags: web2py

The specific functionality I'm looking for:

A member creates a page to display information. The member can keep the page public, or set to "private" so that only a select group can view it. When the member sets the page to private, they enter a password. The member then shares this password with people they want to view the page. When a visitor gets to the page, they are prompted to enter the password. If the password is correct, the page can be viewed by the visitor.

Do I need to force visitors to register, then check against a list to see if the visitor has been approved to access the page? Is there a good / better way to think about this in Web2py?

Comment: I don't know what you need to do with that page exactly, but if the member only wants to send the user to that page one time, the `session.uuid` could be an other solution. In that case, If you think that could work, let me know, I will then post an answer.

Comment: The page exists so that visitors can submit information, via a form, to the page owner. With the private page, the page owner wants to limit input to a specific group of people.  Visitors may or may not be interested in returning to the page at a later date to see a summary of results. I don't know a lot about sessions, but it may work if your thought is for the app to generate unique links that the member then sends to visitors, and then associate those links to sessions that are only authorized once. Interesting thought. Could I set the number of visits allowed?

Comment: Yes, my thought was to generate a link to a unique URL for the visitor to visit the page. The user can visit the page multiple times during the session; however, this URL will raise HTTP(404) if the user closes the browser and then later tries to copy the URL in the browser again.

Comment: There is an other option the `@auth.requires_signature()` this may work better for you. I will post it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web2py has some powerful **access control** features built in. See this [link.](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control) Basically you can create groups and add/remove users (members) to these groups. If the user is a member of a group, you can allow or disallow access to certain things.

> For example, lets create a group and add some memberships in a model or controller:

```
#get the id of the user logged in
user_id = auth.user_id

#make a new group just for viewing this page
new_group_id = auth.add_group(
     "private_page_by_user_%s" % user_id,
     "This is a private page made by user id # %s" % user_id
)

#make the creator a member
auth.add_membership(new_group_id, user_id)

#for simplicity
friend_id = 5

#add friends to the group, so they can view the private page
auth.add_membership(new_group_id, friend_id)
```

> Now in the "page" controller you can allow or block users based on their membership:

```
def page():
     #... stuff
     #... more stuff
     if page_is_private and not auth.has_membership(group_id=group_id): #or you can do auth.has_membership(role="private_page_by_user_1")
          redirect(URL("access_denied"))
     #... continue
```

Comment: Reasonable solution if your app requires membership / authentication. How could this be done for anonymous users where auth.user_id does not exist? I'm not saying your solution isn't the right solution. We may need to require membership. Just want to get a sense of if / how this could be done without it.

Comment: Without auth, guests would either need a shared password or a single-use link that remains valid during life-span of the session. Both ways have their drawbacks.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the single-use link that remains valid during the life of the session? Would there be one link for each visitor that the member wants to send to the page? This may be sort of what Joe R. is referring to above. I think that may actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a link on an other page or email the user the link to the `test` page. For the `test` page, you can have this in the controller:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def test():
    redirect(URL('sign_page',user_signature=True))
    return dict(link=link)
```

On the `test` page the user can register and login. The `test` page then redirects the user to the page you only want this user to access, so this page requires the user's `signature`:

```
@auth.requires_signature() 
def sign_page():
    return dict(message='Welcome to this page')
```